# Identify adjacent shapes in a canvas

Tags: c#, canvas, geometry, drawing, shapes

How can I determine if two shapes are adjacent in canvas using the coordinates of the shape? I have following situation.

[image]

I need to find out adjacent shapes of Shape 1. Visually we can say it is Shape 2. But, how can I determine it programmatically. All I have is coordinates of the shape. I need to determine horizontally, vertically and diagonally adjacent shapes. Shapes may or may not be aligned. Also there can be different shapes like circle, triangle, etc.

Comment: Are you going to have shapes around all four sides of shape1? What do you want to happen if two shapes are on the same side of shape1 and are the same distance from shape1? Do you want both to be stored for use? Will shape1 always be a rectangle or can it also be one of the other shapes?

Comment: Yes the shapes will be around all four sides plus the diagonal sides. If two shapes are on same side and at same distance, they both should be marked as adjacent shapes. Shape 1 can be any shape but it is bounded inside a rectangle as we see in drawing software like Paint, Adobe XD, etc. and its coordinates are available.